# remove by ID passed from array jquery or JS or underscore

Tags: jquery, arrays, dom

I have ID's stored in array and I need to remove the associated ID's from my page. The part that I'm confused on is passing the variable in to know what ID's to remove 
I'm hoping that I'm fairly close to being right.

```
$.each(diff, function () {
            $('ul#jdl li').remove();
        });
```

"diff" is the array containing the ID's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you if I understand your question correctly:

```
$.each(diff, function (index, value) {
        $('ul#jdl li#' + value).remove();
    });
```

Comment: If you got an ID for an object, it's unnecessary to do $('#ID1 #ID2'), don't forget that an ID is unique so just simple call $('#ID2')

Comment: agreed, it was just because the selector was already there I assumed it might not have been as unique as it should be :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your array is something like below, I would suggest just looping through it.

```
var idarray = ["id1","id2","id3"];

for (var i=0;i<idarray.length;i++)
{
 $("#"+idarray[i]).remove();
}
```

You can see a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/h6vGz/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(diff, function (index, value) {
    $("#" + value).remove();
});
```

Since you're working with IDs, you don't need to include the UL part in the selector. `$("#something").remove()` will always be sufficient.

Furthermore, you don't need to put a tagname before an ID, e.g. `ul#jdl`. It is faster and shorter to just use `#jdl`.

Comment: that's fair i'll make the modification

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

```
for (i=0; i < diff.length; i++) {
    $("#" + diff[i]).remove();
}
```